# CocoaPods: Can I have two Pods projects with different dependencies and settings

Tags: cocoapods

Related to transitive binary dependencies.

Can I have this scenario - two Pods projects for the same my project one of them use use_frameworks! with Swift dependencies and other doesn't use use_frameworks! and with static binary dependencies.

Comment: I tried to ask this question in issues on github of CocoaPods, but they said to ask it there

Answer (score 2):

So, I think now this is not possible, because name of Pods project can't be changed. There can be two Pods project with same name in xCode workspace, but their target names also will be Pods and only one of them could be linked with main project.
With current version of cocoa pods this is not possible.
I tried this as a mean to use static transitive binary dependency with use_frameworks! option. I've found another way to achieve this - just wrap this transitive binary dependency to framework manually and declare vendored_frameworks.